# Javascript function setData reuse

Tags: javascript, function

Thanks for coming in for help. I can't figure out a better title for this question. But please help me with this.

I have **multiple** input fields. *input1, input2, input3,and input4*. The below function is **input1 and input2**. I would like to check if the input data is a number or not and also check if it's paste or not. and **inputValue1 and inputValue2 ** are the variable I want to check and change.

```
  input1: function (e) {
    if (Math.abs(e.detail.value.length - this.data.inputValue1.length) != 1) {
      this.setData({
        inputValue1: ''
      })
      return ''
    } else {
      let reg = /^[0-9]*$/
      if (!reg.test(e.detail.value)) {
        this.setData({
          inputValue1: ''
        })
        return ''
      } else {
        this.setData({
          inputValue1:e.detail.value
        })
      }
    }
  },
  input2: function (e) {
    if (Math.abs(e.detail.value.length - this.data.inputValue2.length) != 1) {
      this.setData({
        inputValue2: ''
      })
      return ''
    } else {
      let reg = /^[0-9]*$/
      if (!reg.test(e.detail.value)) {
        this.setData({
          inputValue2: ''
        })
        return ''
      } else {
        this.setData({
          inputValue2:e.detail.value
        })
      }
    }
  },
```

Because the code is long, I would like to reuse it instead of hard coding it. This is my approach.

```
  checkInput:function(INPUT) {
    if (Math.abs(e.detail.value.length - this.data.INPUT.length) != 1) {
      this.setData({
        INPUT: ''
      })
      return ''
    } else {
      let reg = /^[0-9]*$/
      if (!reg.test(e.detail.value)) {
        this.setData({
          INPUT: ''
        })
        return ''
      } else {
        this.setData({
          INPUT:e.detail.value
        })
      }
    }
  },
```

then I want to use this

```
input1: function (e) {
  this.checkInput(inputValue1)
},
input2: function (e) {
  this.checkInput(inputValue2)
},
input3: function (e) {
  this.checkInput(inputValue3)
}
```

When I tried these it shows

> ReferenceError: inputValue1 is not defined

Then I tried another approach

```
input1: function (e) {
  this.checkInput(this.data.inputValue1)   
},
```

This time it shows,

> ReferenceError: e is not defined

Best Regards

Comment: do you mean you don't want copy and paste and what error are you getting?

Comment: @UdenduAbasili Thanks for your comment. I updated the question. hope that clears the question a bit more.